# How to replicate node.js code in react native?

Tags: node.js, react-native, cryptojs

I need to do exact same thing as following code, in a react native (android) project. Couldn't find anything similar. I have tried rn-nodeify but it gives an error when installing. Is there any other way to do this in react native.

```
var hash = require('crypto');

var data = hash.createHash('SHA512').update(some_string + some_key_value).digest('hex');
```

Comment: did u try google react native crypto? It shows a react-native-crypto package that seems to do what you want.

Comment: yes. I tried. https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-crypto
but I couldn't complete it because it gave me an error when I call the command - npm i --save-dev tradle/rn-nodeify